# Is it possible that window.open throwed SyntaxError exception

Tags: javascript, html

Due with some researching I came across onto `window.open` API. [From here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#apis-for-creating-and-navigating-browsing-contexts-by-name%3Aparse-a-url) I got knowledge that the `window.open` may throw an `SyntaxError`. But I can't reproduce it, does somebody know how to trigger the error relating to this document https://chromestatus.com/feature/5636515271016448?

Comment: From your link, click on "Additional fields by process phase", then click on the github link, and click on the first link in the post. You'll see examples

Comment: @blex thanks. I've found next thing http://w3c-test.org/url/failure.html